# Netbeans source tabs missing

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-7.3

I install fresh NB 7.3 and when create new php project source tab is missing. I create in source files new file index.php and when double click on index.php he show me history. No source tab for eddintig sorurce.

Check screenshot.
 http://forums.netbeans.org/files/screenshot_118.png

Answer (score 0):

As a last resort, go into Window > Reset Windows (after Configure Windows). This will close the window, then re-dock everything back to look like a fresh installation.

Comment: I do that but again some problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it?